# Do people with sociopathy, neuroticism need medical attention?

Tags: neuroscience, psychiatry

Do people with sociopathy, neuroticism need medical attention? I thought people with dark traits don't need medication unless it causes them to have problem functioning in society like working with other people and getting along with their colleagues. Most DSM V definitions seem to suggest that they're not conditions that need medical attention unless it does cause them difficulty functioning. I am correct in saying this, how am I wrong if I am wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. Please feel free to view the site [tour]. What do you mean by medical help? Pharmaceutical intervention? Or do you include talking therapies? Sociopathy and neuroticism are 2 distinctly different problems. Which would you like to focus on with this question and what have you read which makes you think someone with that problem can possibly carry on without some kind of intervention?

Comment: "Need" maybe too strong a term. Perhaps consider "need" versus "would benefit from". A common goal is to increase happiness. Sociopathy and neuroticism seem at odds with happiness. Therefore, seeking help (medical or psychological) may overcome hinderances to achieving happiness.